# Same thread is created 3 times instead of 3 different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I run this code:

```
        threads = new Thread[length];

        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            threads[j] = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread "+j+" has started!");
            });
            threads[j].Start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Join();
        }
```

Why do I get this output: (if length=3)

```
Thread 3 has started!
Thread 3 has started!
Thread 3 has started!
```

Shouldnt I get the output like this:

```
Thread 0 has started!
Thread 1 has started!
Thread 2 has started!
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There are 3 different threads, but they share the same `j`. Lambdas capture variables by reference, not by value. If you define variable `j2 = j` inside the `for` loop and print it, you won't run into this problem.

Comment: Yes, but how can I "index" the threads, for example, if I want the first thread to do something, and the second thread to do something else and so on?
I've tried creating a variable in the thread -> int index = j; 
But it's still the same

Comment: @CodesInChaos: My understanding was that lambdas actually capture (or 'hoist') the variable *itself* into the closure - so no reference *or* value is actually taken or copied.

Comment: @Baldrick That's not really semantically different from creating a reference to it.  That is the mechanism by which it accomplishes those semantics.